# Error In AutoWiring the Bean Class with the RestController

Tags: java, spring

**DAO Interface**

```
@Repository
public interface UserDAO {
    // some methods...
}
```

**DAO Implementation class** (use @Repository Annotation)

```
@Repository("userDAO")
public class UserDAOImpl {
    // some implementation code.
}
```

**Service Interface**

```
@Service
public interface UserService {
    // some methods...
}
```

**Service Class** (use @Service Annotation)

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl {
    // implementation o service method...
}
```

**RestController** (use @Autowired Annotation)

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200" , allowedHeaders="*")
public class UserRestController {
    //  Autowired the Service class
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userService")
    private UserService userService;
    // implementation code...
}
```

After all these steps I am still getting the Following exception.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.javatpoint.LoginLogoutRest.service.TokenService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=tokenService)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
    ... 30 more

    Jul 20, 2018 5:12:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userLoginRestController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'tokenService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.javatpoint.LoginLogoutRest.service.TokenService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=tokenService)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1348)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:499)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:172)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4829)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5139)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3700)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:5461)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1366)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.javatpoint.LoginLogoutRest.service.TokenService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=tokenService)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
    ... 30 more
```

And I am making this project with no XML.

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: what is TokenService? where is it used?

Comment: What do you understand from this message? - `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.javatpoint.LoginLogoutRest.service.TokenService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.`

Comment: This error is related to `com.javatpoint.LoginLogoutRest.service.TokenService` class, check in this class `userLoginRestController` if you did not create that bean, you need to create that bean and do Autowire

Comment: Hi pvpKiran , TokenService is a service class which is invoked in the RestController.

Comment: Hi Deadpool , when I use Annotation like Repository, Service then I think I don't need to create the bean manually.

Answer (score 0):

No need to put @service annotation inside Interface

for example on DAO interface and service interface

```
  public interface UserDAO {
    // some methods...
    }

//Service
public interface UserService {
  // some methods...
}
```

Comment: is there any class name TokenService?

Answer (score 0):

I forget to implement the Interface. This is what the problem is.

In DAO Implementation class it should be like

```
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {  }
```

In Service class it should be like

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {  }
```